# How properly replace elements using node-html-parser library?

Tags: javascript, node-html-parser

I am trying to replace all links in body to spans like this.

```
map((body) => {
      let dom = parse(body.toString());
      dom.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((link) => {
        dom.exchangeChild(link, parse(`<span>lalala</span>`));
      });
      return dom;
    })
```

Any suggestions or guesses why this is not working?

Comment: Can you please expound upon "_this is not working_"? I am not familiar with `exchangeChild()`. Are you perhaps looking for [`replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)?

Comment: Never mind about `replaceChild()`... looks like [`node-html-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) returns an enhanced HTMLElement with custom methods, including `exchangeChild()`.